# show jquery dialog

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery

On [this site](http://iranfairco.com/example/dialog.aspx) Firefox show jQuery dialog(waiting) but in IE8 it does not show jQuery dialog(waiting)

```
$("#wait").dialog({resizable:false,width:100,modal:true,height:100 });
$("#wait").siblings(".ui-dialog-titlebar").hide(); 

var  certification = "";
var address;
var  idCompany="821225021";

for (var  i = 0; i < 10; i++)                                 
{ 
    idCompany =idCompany + i.toString();
    idCompany=idCompany + ".png";
    address="../Image/CertificationCompany/"+idCompany; 

    if (UrlExists(address))
    {
        certification +="<a>";
        certification +="<img style='width:40px;height:40px;' src='../Image/CertificationCompany/" + idCompany + "'  />";
        certification +="</a>";                                                                                            
    }

    idCompany="821225021";
}

$("#contentCertification").html(certification);
$("#wait").dialog('close');
```

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happens in Chrome but I think it might be a speed issue, in that the browser is *too* fast and displays then hides the dialog.

If you debug and step through the JavaScript in Chrome and break at the point when the `dialog()` is created, it appears as expected.

You need to close the dialog after the last XMLHTTPRequest has finished and you could do this by acting on the `readyState` of the XMLHTTPRequest object (see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535874%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/xmlhttprequest) documentation).

That said, since you are already using jQuery, I strongly suggest using the jQuery [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) method for all your requests, which obfuscates the differences between browsers when performing asynchronous HTTP requests (and *a lot* of other browser differences!). You then get cross-browser compliant code *and* a clean callback mechanism, for example:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) { 
    address="../Image/CertificationCompany/"+ idCompany + i.toString() + ".png";

    $.get(address, function(data) {
        var certification = $('<a/>')
            .append('<img style="width:40px;height:40px;" src="' + address + '"/>');

        $("#contentCertification").append(certification);

        if ($('#contentCertification a').length == 10) {
            $("#wait").dialog('close');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What is the solution
There is another way to show the waiting

Comment: i does not understand.please write a sample

Comment: Added a better example, but this is currently untested

Comment: The code was not something that could be just copied and pasted! You may need to check it first :-) Let me have another look.

Comment: It's difficult to create working code without a good demo of your problem, however the updated code should work.